# can't access parent ctrl in $compile directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a recursive nested navigation menu in AngularJS. I have a  directive and it can have any number of  elements. It looks a bit like this:

```
<root-nav>
    <sub-nav-tree navData="menuItem">
</root-nav>
```

The root-nav directive holds a RootNav controller, I can't access this controller from the child directive in the DOM. The parent controller holds a bunch of methods which can be used in the child directive, but I can't access it. And I don't want redundant code (copy/paste methods to child controller).

What i wan't is this to work

The sub-nav-tree directive compiles a template, so I'm pretty sure its the $compile part thats the bad guy.

this is the part of the linking function in the child directive:

```
    if (scope.menuItem && scope.menuItem.children && scope.menuItem.children.length > 0) {

        $http.get('/markup/components/root-navigation/sub-navigation.html').then(function (response) {
            el.replaceWith($compile(response.data)(scope));
        });

    }
```

Hope you guys can help me out with this problem :) Thanks.

@Chandermani here's the child directives return function:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^^rootNav',
    scope: {
        menuItem: '=navData'
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, rootNavCtrl) {

        if (scope.menuItem && scope.menuItem.children && scope.menuItem.children.length > 0) {

            $http.get('/markup/components/root-navigation/sub-navigation.html').then(function (response) {
                el.replaceWith($compile(response.data)(scope);
            });

        }

    },
}
```

Comment: The parent controller is available in child directive link function. Where are you trying to access the parent controller function. Please share that code.

Comment: I've added the code in the question. If I was able to pass the rootNavCtrl to $compile() somehow?

Comment: They way to pass the controller would be to just assing scope.root=rootNavCtrl

Comment: Hmm I must have made a mistake at one point, cause I tried this as well but didn't work, but now it does. Thank you :)